# Why does postgres query always return null for primary key?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I'm just getting started with Node.js and Postgres and have been able to execute queries without issues until recently. I am trying to execute the following query using node-postgres:

```
"SELECT * FROM " +
"users u LEFT JOIN details d ON u.id = d.id " + 
"WHERE u.email = '" + email + "'"
```

The query runs fine and it returns the row I need but the id field (which is the primary key) is returned with a null value instead of the actual id.

If I run the same query in pgadmin, I can see that the id is actually populated.

Any ideas what it could be? I'm new to postgres so this might be something very simple.

Thanks in advance!

### EDIT

The results returned from the query above are:

```
{"id":null,"first_name":"test","last_name":"test","email":"test@gmail.com","password":"$2b$10$a03zXBCm1OHc9Dc4RhV/buc5BRIuruloGH7lsAS2sK7Mzi0.rrXrO","company":"test","user_type":"Web","is_verified":true,"created_date":"2021-02-22T12:13:53.906Z","modified_date":"2021-02-22T12:14:01.740Z","active":null,"access_token":null,"refresh_token":null,"token_expires_in":null,"token_updated_at":null,"date_connected":null}
```

My expectation was that since this is a left join, there would be 1 id for the users table which is not null, and another id for the details table which is null. This is the result that I get when I run the query in pgadmin. Below is my JavaScript for running this query.

```
getUserByEmail: function (email) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var output = {};
        const query = {
            text: "SELECT u.id, * FROM " +
                  "users u LEFT JOIN hubspot_oauth h ON u.id = h.id " + 
                  "WHERE u.email = '" + email + "'"
        }

        db.query(query, (err, res) => {
            if (err) {
                reject("Some error message.");
            } else {
                console.log("QUERY RESULTS: " + JSON.stringify(res.rows[0]));

                resolve(res.rows[0]);
            }
        });
    });
},
```

Comment: Can you provide a script to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan I have added additional details in the original post.

Comment: Did you try fixing the query as suggested in the answer? Which column is the foreign key in the `hubspot_oauth` table?

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of d.id, there should be d.user_id.

"SELECT * FROM " +
"users u LEFT JOIN details d ON u.id = d.user_id " +
"WHERE u.email = '" + email + "'"`

Comment: You have 2 id columns and your description is ambiguous. You say id column is null, but which one? In this case however it must be details.id. A PK **cannot** be null if it exists. You however doing a LEFT join. Left join says if there is no match for the ON condition return the listed columns from the left side mentioned table and NULL for all columns from the right side mentioned table. Since you used select * this means return null for all columns on the right mentioned table when no rows satisfy the on condition.  What you are getting is not a problem; it is a consequence of your query.

Comment: @Belayer the PK is not null in the users table and I agree with what you are saying, I was expecting the id from the users table to be populated while the id (and the other columns) from the details table to be null but for some reason In the response, I am not seeing a value for the id. Should I populate the id in the query manually like "u.id, *".